# Internet speed is slower than other PC/Laptop on my LAN

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ethernet, internet-speed

I have subscribed for 40Mbps Internet connection. But in my PC I have just 10Mbps (with CAT 6 Ethernet cable and Intel(R) 82578DC Gigabit Network Connection). I have also tested the internet speed online. It reaches only up to 9Mbps.

I have another PC which is also connected via Ethernet. It reaches up to 40Mbps.
The results of both tests.

PC1
[image]

PC2
[image]

I have also laptops and mobile phones connected to the router with wireless. But they even reach more than 30Mbps.

Could anyone help me solve this problem in PC1?
In PC1 I have installed Oracle VirtualBox. Can the VirtuaBbox bridged network driver have influence on the internet speed?

Comment: Did you check The speed & Duplex value in your NIC?
To do this , see the Advanced properties of your NIC in device manager.

Comment: @Scorpion99 It's set on "Auto Negotiation"

Comment: Can you set it to 100 Mbps Full Duplex then disable and enable the NIC and test your connection

Comment: @Scorpion99 great! it works. Now my pc reaches up to 33Mbps. It's much better. Could you please explain me why Auto Negotiation didn't work? In other PC it is also set Auto, but there it worked.

Comment: Check how Autonegotiation works:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonegotiation
Could you please accept the provided answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your device manager , select your NIC and check the Advanced properties.
Change the Speed & Duplex to 100 Mbps Full Duplex

[image]